# AndroidManifest.xml - No resource identifier found for attribute 'launchmode' in package 'android'

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to use a single instance of an activity when NFC is triggered. Adding android:launchmode="singleTask" should do the trick, but I get an error when I configure the launch mode:

> Attribute android:launchmode is not allowed here

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >

        <activity
            android:name=".NFCReader"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchmode="singleTask" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `android:launchMode` not `android:launchmode`.